# use string variable in forEach() loop to fetch data in angular

Tags: angularjs

can i use string variable in angular.forEach() loop like this:

```
var variable= "keyname";
angular.forEach($scope.arrCategory[0].variable,function(k,d){
    //alert(k);
    angular.forEach(k,function(kk, dd){
        alert(dd);
    });
});
```

if it is wrong how should i use this variable in loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property by variable name:

```
var variable = "keyname";
angular.forEach($scope.arrCategory[0][variable], function(k,d) {
    angular.forEach(k, function(kk, dd) {
        alert(dd);
    });
});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
angular.forEach($scope.arrCategory[0].["static"],function(k,d){........  : this was the console message when handle it in your way

Comment: @thathsara you forgot to remove the dot before the opening bracket

Comment: thanx. it works.actually a have done a really big mistake @  JB Nizet.